# Update stored procedure query using SQL Server table type - how to?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I already have a working stored procedure that takes data from tabletype like in this example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tblDefQ_Detail_INSERT]
  @Quotient_D Quotient_D  READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Quotient_D ([q_id], [item_id], [item_name])
       SELECT 
           [q_id], [item_id], [item_name] 
       FROM 
           @Quotient_D 
 END
```

This stored procedure takes values from table type as coded

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Quotient_D] AS TABLE(
[q_id] [int] NULL,
[item_id] [int] NULL,
[item_name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

This works fine.

What I want now is an `UPDATE` stored procedure that take values from this table type using where clause on

```
q_id
```

Comment: So what's your question about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tblDefQ_Detail_UPDATE]
  @Quotient_D Quotient_D  READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE original 
    SET item_id = temp.item_id, 
        item_name = temp.item_name
    FROM @Quotient_D temp
    JOIN Quotient_D original ON temp.q_id = original.q_id
END
```

Comment: iif there are three rows it duplicating every row

Comment: it is not inserting extra record like updating 2 existing but third addition not works

Comment: as long as you maintain id unique it should match one record; if your q_id is not unique / primary key in your db, use relevant field to join there

Comment: this query only updates but not inserts new; you should combine logic in both stored procedures to do your task

Comment: i have to add new record during updation even

Comment: @office302: `UPDATE` only ever updates existing rows - it never inserts new rows

Comment: while updating image error is `nvarchar(max) is incompatible with image
The data for table-valued parameter "@Quotient_D_UP"`